# Correctly parsed LocalDate causes BindingResult errors. Why?

Tags: spring-boot, date, post, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm stumped. I have a domain class `Period` with two `LocalDate` properties `start` and `end` plus a corresponding controller method and template to create new periods.

The problem: Even though the request model is evidently correctly deserialized into a `Period` instance with two correct `LocalDate` properties, I *still* get errors in the `BindingResult`, where the properties are apparently *not* converted to `LocalDate` but remain as `String`s instead. The validation fails with:

```
end: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]
start: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'start'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-01]
```

This is the domain class:

```kotlin
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "period")
    class Period(
    
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long = 0,
    
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        var start: LocalDate?,
    
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        var end: LocalDate?,
    )
```

This is the controller method for creating a new Period:

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("/period/add")
        fun updatePeriod(@ModelAttribute("period") @Validated period: Period, result: BindingResult, model: Model) : String {
            if(result.hasErrors()){
                result
                    .getFieldErrors()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach{f -> println(f.getField() + ": " + f.getDefaultMessage())};
                return "add-period"
            }
            else {
                periodRepository.save(period)
                return "redirect:/period"
            }
    
        }
```

And this is the Thymeleaf template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="'New Period'"></h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/period/add}" th:object="${period}" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date</td>
        <td><input id="start" type="date"  name="start"
                   min="2000-01-01" max="2023-12-31"
                   th:value="*{start}"
                   th:field="*{start}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End Date</td>
        <td><input id="end" type="date"  name="end"
                   min="2000-01-01" max="2023-12-31"
                   th:value="*{end}"
                   th:field="*{end}"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this is what the debugger tells me when setting a break point at `if(result.hasErrors()){` in the controller. Clearly, `period` is a `Period` instance with two `LocalDate` properties, each with a year, month and day (indicated by `-->`). The same is true inside the `BindingResult`. Everything is fine!

Yet, there are two errors which reject the String values used to create the dates (indicated by `==>`).

```
    this = {WebController@13784} nl.tracking.core.web.WebController@a4388f1
    period = {Period@13787} nl.tracking.core.domain.Period@111cd8c3
     id = 0
-->  start = {LocalDate@17522} "2022-06-01"
-->   year = 2022
-->   month = 6
-->   day = 1
     end = {LocalDate@17523} "2022-06-02"
    result = {BeanPropertyBindingResult@13788} "org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors\nField error in object 'period' on field 'end': rejected value [2022-06-02]; codes [typeMismatch.period.end,typeMismatch.end,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [period.end,end]; arguments []; default message [end]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]]\nField error in object 'period' on field 'start': rejected value [2022-06-01]; codes [typeMismatch.period.start,typeMismatch.start,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springfra"
-->  target = {Period@13787} nl.tracking.core.domain.Period@111cd8c3
     autoGrowNestedPaths = true
     autoGrowCollectionLimit = 256
     beanWrapper = {BeanWrapperImpl@17526} "org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl: wrapping object [nl.tracking.core.domain.Period@111cd8c3]"
     conversionService = {WebConversionService@17527} "ConversionService converters =\n\t@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.lang.Long -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@4a422ef1,@org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Long -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@35e37f8f\n\t@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@1f4c8763,java.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@61841139\n\t@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@1f4c8763,java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAcces"
     objectName = "period"
     messageCodesResolver = {DefaultMessageCodesResolver@17529} 
     errors = {ArrayList@17530}  size = 2
      0 = {FieldError@17550} "Field error in object 'period' on field 'end': rejected value [2022-06-02]; codes [typeMismatch.period.end,typeMismatch.end,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [period.end,end]; arguments []; default message [end]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]]"
       field = "end"
==>    rejectedValue = "2022-06-02"
       bindingFailure = true
       objectName = "period"
==>    source = {TypeMismatchException@17556} "org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]"
       codes = {String[4]@17557} ["typeMismatch.pe...", "typeMismatch.en...", "typeMismatch.ja...", "typeMismatch"]
       arguments = {Object[1]@17558} 
==>    defaultMessage = "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]"
      1 = {FieldError@17551} "Field error in object 'period' on field 'start': rejected value [2022-06-01]; codes [typeMismatch.period.start,typeMismatch.start,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [period.start,start]; arguments []; default message [start]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'start'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-01]]"
     fieldTypes = {HashMap@17531}  size = 0
     fieldValues = {HashMap@17532}  size = 0
     suppressedFields = {HashSet@17533}  size = 0
     nestedPath = ""
     nestedPathStack = {ArrayDeque@17535}  size = 0
--> model = {BindingAwareModelMap@13789}  size = 2
     "period" -> {Period@13787} nl.tracking.core.domain.Period@111cd8c3
      key = "period"
      value = {Period@13787} nl.tracking.core.domain.Period@111cd8c3
       id = 0
-->    start = {LocalDate@17522} "2022-06-01"
-->     year = 2022
-->     month = 6
-->     day = 1
       end = {LocalDate@17523} "2022-06-02"
     "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.period" -> {BeanPropertyBindingResult@13788} "org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors\nField error in object 'period' on field 'end': rejected value [2022-06-02]; codes [typeMismatch.period.end,typeMismatch.end,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [period.end,end]; arguments []; default message [end]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'end'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2022-06-02'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-06-02]]\nField error in object 'period' on field 'start': rejected value [2022-06-01]; codes [typeMismatch.period.start,typeMismatch.start,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springfra"
```

It makes no sense to me... I searched S/O far and wide but can't find a solution. Most people either use a mismatching `@DateTimeFormat` pattern or are lacking thymeleaf-extras-java8time.

I'm using spring-boot 2.6.7 and thymeleaf 3.0.15. I have added thymeleaf-extras-java8time to the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I had to do to fix this is use:

```kotlin
@field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

instead of:

```kotlin
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

In my domain class.